# Strategy.exit: What are "points" in this context? V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Example from manual:

```
strategy.exit("exit", "long", profit = 10, loss = 5) // generate full exit bracket (profit 10 points, loss 5 points per contract) from entry with name "long"
```

Are these points percents? So if this position was worth $100 (when opened) then `profit = 10` point is 10% = $10 so we sold the position for $110?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are [pips](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/pip.asp#:%7E:text=Pip%20is%20an%20acronym%20for,last%20(fourth)%20decimal%20point.).

> A pip is the smallest price move that an exchange rate can make based
> on forex market convention.

If you want to do a percentage based exit, you should use the `limit` and `stop` arguments.

```
in_long_tp_per = input.float(2.0, "Take profit %") * 0.01
in_long_sl_per = input.float(1.0, "Stop loss %") * 0.01

long_tp_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + in_long_tp_per)
long_sl_price = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - in_long_sl_per)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit("exit", "long", limit = long_tp_price, stop = long_sl_price)
```